# My PHP/ PDO query only returns 7 records when it should return 9

Tags: javascript, php, oracle, pdo

I have a web app that queries an Oracle Database for ID's that don't have X,Y's, I'm using Jquery and PHP API's,
I'm passing a list of ID's to PHP to query the database, and returning more information on the records so I can geoCode them. 
For some reason my code skips the first and last record and only returns 7 of the 9.

In SQL Developer, My SQL query returns 9 records, which is correct. 
My JavaScript, My Array (theIDS) has the 9 record IDS
 that I'm selecting on, these are the same I used in SQL Developer.

My PHP page processes the array and returns 7 of the 9. Skips first and last.

In SQL Developer, My SQL query returns 9 records, which is correct.

```
SELECT ID, M_ADD1,M_CITY,M_STATE FROM CI_Data
  WHERE ID IN
('1129','135','158','306','325','397','630','755','776');
```

My JavaScript code:

```
var theIDS = ["1129", "135", "158", "306", "325", "397", "630", "755", "776"];

var phpIDS = theIDS.join();

// My AJAX call to the PHP to pass the array and return the records.
    $.ajax({ url : "forgeocode.php",
        type       : 'POST',                                             
    data       : {'data': JSON.stringify(phpIDS)},
    success    : function(result){
        console.log(result.length + "   Records");
        console.log(result);

        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                        console.log(result[i][0]+ " ID Number");
                        console.log(result[i][1]);
                         console.log(i);
        }
    }
});
```

My PHP page that gets the POST and queries the records

```
$db = new PDO('oci:dbname=//myDBName:1521/infrastructuregisdev', 'Acct', 'Pwd');;

$arrData= $_POST['data'];
$arr = explode(",",$arrData);
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($arr) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "SELECT ID, M_ADD1,M_CITY,M_STATE FROM CIGIS.CI_DATA WHERE ID IN ($in)";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute($arr);
$data = $stm->fetchAll();

header('content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

I need all 9 records, not sure if it's the PHP page using PDO. Why is it skipping the first and last record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending the string as JSON in JavaScript, so you need to use `json_decode()` in PHP.

```
$arrData= json_decode($_POST['data']);
```

If you don't do this, there are double quotes in `$arrData`. And after you explode it, the first value is `'"1129'` and the last is `'776"'`. These won't match the ID's in the table.

There's not really any need to convert the string to JSON in the first place, though. In fact, there isn't even any need to convert the array to a string. Just send the array, it will be encoded properly. Use this in the JavaScript:

```
    data       : {'data': theIDS},
```

and

```
$arr = $_POST['data'];
```

in PHP.

Comment: Nailed it, either using json_decode in the PHP or dropping the JSON.stringify in my JavaScript produced a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.stringify(phpIDS)
```

This will create the following:

> "1129,135,158,306,325,397,630,755,776"

Which is then passed to PHP, which you are using the following code on:

```
$arr = explode(",",$arrData);
```

But the problem is that you are exploding a string on ',' which will give you the following values:

> "1129
>   135
>   158
>   306
>   325
>   397
>   630
>   755
>   776"

So when you try to run your "IN ()" on that it cannot match the first and last value.  I think you see why?

So, you'd need to adjust things and run json_decode on the string first.

```
$arrData= json_decode($_POST['data']);
```

And then query your database!

Happy programming.

Comment: I see Barmar posted a similar but slightly more complete answer, so I stopped typing mine.

Comment: Thank you both, your answers make sense. I tried the select IN all morning, then found out I had to use PDO, and the sample code I found didn't have many comments. I though I had it when data came back then I saw the record count. Thanks for the fast response and I'll try them in the morning.